# Is there a way to have a Stack data structure take up part-by-part of a file that is parsed with other parts of coding?

Tags: java

I have the following file and would like for it to first be parsed into pieces. While it is being parsed, it is being pushed into stack data structure such that at the end there is suppose to be no other string in the stack resulting in a 'valid' outcome since all of which was pushed is then popped per the if/else statements. I am getting an error instead.

File(.xml) content:

```
<config><title>title to display on welcome screen goes here</title><copyright>copyright info goes here</copyright><developer>developer info goes here</developer</config>
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Config.<init>(Config.java:20)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Main:

```
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            File myObj = new File("atm.log");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //while(true)
        //{
        /*ATM atm = new ATM();
        atm.init();
        atm.run();*/
        //}
        String name = "atm.xml";
        Config info = new Config(name);

    }
}
```

Class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Config {
    HashMap<String, String> obj = new HashMap<>();

    Stack obj2 = new Stack();


    public Config(String name) throws Exception {
        try {
            File myObj = new File("atm.xml");

            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);

            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                if(myReader.nextLine() == "<config>" || myReader.nextLine() == "<title>" || myReader.nextLine() == "<copyright>" || myReader.nextLine() == "<developer>")
                {
                    obj2.push(myReader.nextLine());
                    System.out.println(obj2.peek());
                }
                else
                {
                    obj2.pop();
                }
                if(obj2.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("Valid");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                }
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `myReader.nextLine()` it reads a line.

Comment: Is there one that reads String pieces, bit by bit?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is an exercise for a course, and you can't use an XML parser. Look at `Scanner.hasNext(String)` (and `Scanner.next(String)`) and remember that you can't compare Strings with `==`!

Comment: it would need to be done with the '.equal(  )'. Gotcha